# Odd behavior with !help command in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to define the brief description for the generic `!help` command and that works fine but I am also trying to define the extended help for the `!help command_name` command so I get get further details on how a command works.

In my command I have defined the details like so:

```
*@client.command()
async def box_custom(ctx, command, *args):
    """Allows the defining of custom commands for a given built in command.
Example: "!custom clear box_clear" will add a new command called !clear.
This will call the box_clear function!

Args:
    command (str): The new command to add.
    args (List[str]): Any additional arguments for the original command.
"""

    # do some stuff here
box_custom.brief = "Define custom command for a given built in command."*
```

When I run my `!help` Command everything looks fine:

```
​No Category:
  box_custom Define custom command for a given built in command.
  box_play   Plays audio from a specified URL.
  help       Shows this message

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

When I run the `!help box_custom` command I get what I defined but I also get some generic placeholder text telling me no description was given.

```
!box_custom

Allows the defining of custom commands for a given built in command.
Example: "!custom clear box_clear" will add a new command called !clear.
This will call the box_clear function!

Args:
    command (str): The new command to add.
    args (List[str]): Any additional arguments for the original command.

Arguments:
  command No description given
  args    No description given
```

I have not been able to find a workable way to either get rid of this extra `Arguments:` section or to at the very least be able to provide a description for it.

Am I missing something here as I have not normally worked with providing descriptions in functions so this is kinda new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DefaultHelpCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#defaulthelpcommand) defaults to showing parameter descriptions. Descriptions for parameters are provided through [`commands.parameter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.parameter):

```py
async def box_custom(
    ctx,
    command: str = commands.parameter(description="The new command to add."),
    *args: list[str] = commands.parameter(description="Any additional arguments for the original command.")
):
```

So you can add all your descriptions that way.

The other way is to override the default help command to *not* show parameter descriptions as you are already including them yourself in the doc string. This saves having to modify all existing commands and your doc string args will still be shown.

```py
help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(show_parameter_descriptions=False)

bot = commands.Bot(
    intents=intents,
    help_command=help_command,
    # whatever other args you're passing here
)
```

You could go further and write your own [help command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand) that extracts the parameter descriptions from the doc string but that seems excessive when either of these options should hopefully resolve this for you.